# Custom Cumulative Sum in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Noob question, apologies.

I am trying to do a cumulative sum on a table I have imported. However I wish for it to perform slightly differently at a mid point in the column before continuing. Is there a way to get a cumsum() to calculate to a row then continue from a further point

```
df['Cumlative Sum'] = df['Value'].cumsum()

|    | Value | Cumlative Sum | Expected Cumlative Sum |
|----|-------|---------------|------------------------|
| 0  | 329.6 | 329.6         | 329.6                  |
| 1  | 34.0  | 363.6         | 363.6                  |
| 2  | 10    | 373.6         | 373.6                  |
| 3  | 8     | 381.6         | 381.6                  |
| 4  | 3     | 384.6         | 384.6                  |
| 5  | -2    | 382.6         | 382.6                  |
| 6  | -4    | 378.6         | 378.6                  |
| 7  | -34   | 344.6         | 344.6                  |
| 8  | -1    | 343.6         | 343.6                  |
| 9  | 343.6 | 687.2         | 343.6                  |
| 10 | 0     | 687.2         | 343.6                  |
| 11 | -33   | 654.2         | 310.6                  |
| 12 | -3    | 651.2         | 307.6                  |
| 13 | 0     | 651.2         | 307.6                  |
| 14 | 1     | 652.2         | 308.6                  |
| 15 | 4     | 656.2         | 312.6                  |
| 16 | 0     | 656.2         | 312.6                  |
| 17 | 21    | 677.2         | 333.6                  |
| 18 | 333.6 | 1010.8        | 333.6                  |
```

Comment: add some data and your code

Comment: See the answer below ..after ..'============================='. I have assumed that the dataframe you have is called df. You can change the 4th line to suit your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df['Group Flag'] = ""
df.loc[0:8, 'Group Flag'] = 0
df.loc[9:17, 'Group Flag'] = 1
df['Cumlative Sum'] = df.groupby('Group Flag')['Value'].cumsum()
df.drop('Group Flag', axis=1)
df[['Title','Value','Cumlative Sum']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get started with something like this ..

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(0,100,size=(20,2)),columns=['A','B'])

def Offset_CumSum(Column, Percentage_Offset=0.5):
    return np.cumsum(Column[int(len(Column)*Percentage_Offset):])

Cumsum_DF = df.apply(lambda x: Offset_CumSum(x), axis=0)
print(df)
print(Cumsum_DF)
```

This produces the following output.

```py
     A   B
0   29  11
1    9  51
2   99  31
3   30  44
4   76  13
5   32  48
6   85  83
7    9  98
8   49  34
9   25   0
10  39  22
11  25  96
12  69   7
13  28   6
14   4  92
15  90  32
16  68  72
17  63  25
18  85  47
19  61  31
      A    B
10   39   22
11   64  118
12  133  125
13  161  131
14  165  223
15  255  255
16  323  327
17  386  352
18  471  399
19  532  430
```

**=====================================================================**

Adding a question dataset specific code after seeing the edit.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(0,100,size=(20,2)),columns=['A','B'])
def Offset_CumSum(Column, Percentage_Offset=0.5):
    return np.cumsum(Column[: int(len(Column)*Percentage_Offset)]).tolist() + np.cumsum(Column[int(len(Column)*Percentage_Offset):]).tolist()

Cumsum_DF = df.apply(lambda x: Offset_CumSum(x), axis=0)
print(df)
print(Cumsum_DF)
```

This should work.

Comment: sorry, could you explain how the code stops and re starts, or in my example how to work it to the expected output in the third column

Comment: You basically make two half computations ..one cumsum for first half and another cumsum for next half and then join these two lists end to end .. you then get what you want ... Will you please paste some code you already have for me to answer how to make it work for you? .. otherwise I will be guessing too much